# Meteor / python / mongoDB - How do I update the mongoDB from a background running process?

Tags: python, mongodb, meteor

I've started creating a meteor app and I want to insert Documents in one of the mongoDB Collections I define using a background task.

Think for example that every day I'm reading an rss feed and scraping a website for news-titles.

**Requirement**

1. Read the rss feed and scrape the necessary website.
2. Put the new titles into the mongoDB Collection used by the meteor App.

**What I know**

I know how to do 1. using python, with `requests` and other libraries.
I know how to add information into a collection through javascript in meteor but *NOT* through a background task by following the `todo` example application tutorial.

**Possible solutions**

1. Get the data in python and then through python add that data to the mongoDB Collection. This would then run on the server on some kind of background process.
2. Use some kind of library from meteor that allows me to run background tasks and webscraping, that I can then use to update the collection.

minimal example taken is from [this step of the todo app](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections).

The step I want to automate:

```
meteor mongo
db.tasks.insert( { text : 'New title' , createdAt: new Date() } );
```

where `New title` is a result of some scrapping / rss feed.

What is the best way to achieve this? I'm relatively fluent in python but completely new to JS and meteor.

**Other comments**

Also, I haven't included this in this example below but I will also want to use the `accounts-ui` and `accounts-password` packages and will remove the `insecure` package. Not sure how this affects the implementation of the background process.

**minimal example**

*(sorry if this isn't very minimal but not sure how to make it smaller)*

- client

  - main.html
  - main.jsx
- server

  - main.js
- imports

  - api

    - tasks.js
  - ui

    - App.jsx
    - Task.jsx

> client/main.html

```
<head>
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='render-target'></div>
</body>
```

> client/main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';                                                                  
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from '../imports/ui/App.jsx';

Meteor.startup( () => {
    render( <App/> , document.getElementById( 'render-target' ) );
});
```

> server/main.js

```
import '../imports/api/tasks.js'
```

> imports/api/tasks.js

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';                                                       

export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection( 'tasks' );
```

> imports/ui/App.jsx

```
import React , { Component , PropTypes } from 'react';                                      
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';

import Task from './Task.jsx';

class App extends Component {

    renderTasks() {
        return this.props.tasks.map( ( task ) => (
            <Task key={task._id} task={task} />
        ) );
    }   

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='container'>
                <header>
                    <h1>Todo List</h1>
                </header>

                <ul>
                    { this. renderTasks() }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }   
}

App.propTypes = { 
    tasks : PropTypes.array.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer( () => {
    return {
        tasks : Tasks.find( {} ).fetch(),
    };  
} , App );
```

> imports/ui/Task.jsx

```
import React, { Component , PropTypes } from 'react';                                       

// Task component - represents a single todo item
export default class Task extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <li>{this.props.task.text}</li>
        );
    }   
}

Task.propTypes = { 
    // This component gets the task to display through a React prop.
    // We can use propTypes to indicate it is required
    task: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the scraping and insertion in the language and tools you know best, since you mention python I assume that will be your choice.  Pymongo makes it very easy to write python dicts into mongo.

You can either run your own version of mongo or access the default one.  To get the connect string for the default, cd into the meteor directory and type:

```
$ meteor mongo -U
```

It will probably be something like mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor.  So, to connect to that from python:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor")                           
db = connection.meteor.tasks
```

Then do the insert:

```
db.insert({ 'text' : title , 'createdAt': datetime.datetime.utcnow()} )
```

If you use your own database the reactive meteor components will be updated every ten seconds (it polls).  If you use the default it will be instant.

Comment: you're god sent! ok sounds like doing it from python is the way to go. The final question I have is that doing this from python do I have to worry at all about authentication etc? ie the same way that in mongo you "publish" a method to the client would I have to publish something to my python script?

Comment: I figured it out. I simply was able to insert items in the db independent of the authentication etc. In retrospect this seems obvious since I guess the database itself isn't authenticating anything

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer!  I only just noticed your question.